# Change values from one column higher than X but not change the others

Tags: r, if-statement

How can I change all values from a column higher than 30 in 30, but if there are lower keep the value that it has?

```
Day Temperature
1            25
2            32
3            28
4            35
```

I want to have

```
Day Temperature
1            25
2            30
3            28
4            30
```

I have tried with ifelse but it also changes the other values.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try either with `ifelse`

```
 df1$Temperature <- with(df1, ifelse(Temperature>30, 30, Temperature))
```

Or in this case, you don't need `ifelse`

```
 df1$Temperature[df1$Temperature>30] <- 30
```

If we are using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Temperature>30, Temperature:=30]
```